# Setting a password using a SecureString

Tags: .net, security, active-directory, directoryservices

Why doesn't `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.SetPassword()` take a `System.Security.SecureString` for the new password?  Is there another approach to changing a password that *does* use a `SecureString`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all password handling APIs in .NET use `SecureString` unfortunately. Not sure why, as the `SecureString` class predates the `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal` by several releases.

You could use the PowerShell cmdlet [`Set-ADAccountPassword`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617261.aspx), which does take a `SecureString`.